# Generic awaitable - how to schedule a continuation?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-standard-2.0, c#-8.0

I'm having an object at hand that may either be a `Task`, a `ValueTask` or a `ValueTask<T>` (optimally I can support any type of awaitable). Regardless of the actual type, I want to schedule a continuation. Optimally the continuation can determine whether the original awaitable has completed successfully, faulted or has been canceled.

How to do that?

My first attempt was:

```
var getAwaiterMethod = invocation.ReturnValue.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Task.GetAwaiter));
var awaiter = (INotifyCompletion) getAwaiterMethod.Invoke(myAwaitableObject, new object[0]);
awaiter.OnCompleted(() => myContinuation);
```

However, in that case the continuation has no way of telling whether the awaitable has completed successfully, faulted or has been canceled.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can `await` a `dynamic` type:

```
dynamic o = myAwaitableObject;
await o;
```

I'm not sure how well that would work with `ValueTask<T>`, though; I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want to await it. I really want to schedule a continuation, because I'm in a non-async context (I'm returning the resulting Task with its continuation in a different form, not via the return type, which is why I can't use await).

Comment: Scheduling continuations **is** what `await` does. If you don't want your code to `await` it directly, then create another `async` method that `await`s the `dynamic`, and then you have a `Task` from that `async` method that you can do with what you wish.

Comment: If someone is using my infrastructure with a `ValueTask` object I would add a non-value `Task` in the mix with your proposed solution. All the reasons my caller would use ValueTask for would be for nothing. Do you see, why I don't wanna go that way?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: A `ValueTask` is safe to be awaited [only once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask#remarks), so having generic library methods for `ValueTask` is dangerous because it can lead to misuse. The general recommendation is: if you want to do anything more fancy with a `ValueTask` beyond awaiting it, use the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask) method to convert it to a `Task` and then forget about it.